# In Excel 2010, how to delete a portion of a string within a cell using a Macro?

Tags: string, excel, split, excel-2010, vba

I am trying to create a macro for an Excel file which has a column (let's call this column A) of cells, and each cell contains 4 to 5 project Deliverables & Work Products separated by a comma, as well as identified by a tag "DEL" for Deliverable and "WKP" for Work Products.

I wish to accomplish the following with a Macro:

1. I would like to keep column A as it is.
2. Create a column B for Deliverables, which need to be extracted from cells in Col A
3. Likewise, create a column C for Work Products, which need to be extracted from cells in Col A

Let me give an example:

Supposing Cell A1 contains

```
DEL1: DEL 1 Project Process, DEL2: DEL 2 Project Schedule, WKP1: WKP 1 Work Product Document
```

Here's what I want Cell B1 to look like:

```
DEL1: DEL 1 Project Process, DEL2: DEL 2 Project Schedule
```

And Cell C1 to look like this:

```
WKP1: WKP1 Work Product Document
```

And mind you, not all the cells in Col A will be the exact character length as Cell A1. But they will contain both DELs and WKPs.

Given that the names of the Deliverables and Work Products vary in length, I cannot simply copy Col A and run TextToColumn in order to split it.

So far, the approach I have come up with is to copy Col A to Col B, retain the Deliverables and try to remove Work Products.

As you can see, this entails deleting the part of the string that starts with the comma (",") and space (" ") in front of "WKP" and ends with the last character of the Work Product in question (which in this case would be the last character of the entire string itself since it seems that the WKPs are mentioned right after DELs).

While I am able to write a Macro the can find the text "WKP" within each cell range and delete it, I am not able to delete the stuff that comes right after it. In other words, I am only able to produce this for Cell B1:

```
DEL1: DEL 1 Project Process, DEL2: DEL 2 Project Schedule, 1: 1 Work Product Document
```

Can someone help me write the Macro to do this? I would appreciate it if the syntax was also explained.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using the "Text to columns" feature on column A to split the contents at the comma. Then you have 5 separate columns to work with, which should be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job. Call it using `=WKP_DEL(A1,"DEL")` in B1 and `=WKP_DEL(A1,"WKP")` in C1.

```
Function WKP_DEL(str As String, DelOrWkp As String) As String

Dim V() As String
Dim SubStr As Variant
Dim WKPs As String
Dim DELs As String
    WKP_DEL = ""
    ' Split the string into an array
    V = Split(str, ",")
    ' Loop through the array adding WKPs to the WKPs string and DELs to the DELs string
    For Each SubStr In V
        If InStr(SubStr, "WKP") > 0 Then
            WKPs = WKPs & Trim(SubStr) & ", "
        End If
        If InStr(SubStr, "DEL") > 0 Then
            DELs = DELs & Trim(SubStr) & ", "
        End If
    Next
    ' Remove the trailing ", " and return the required string
    If DelOrWkp = "DEL" Then WKP_DEL = Left(DELs, Len(DELs) - 2)
    If DelOrWkp = "WKP" Then WKP_DEL = Left(WKPs, Len(WKPs) - 2)
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Jamie, I wanted to thank you so much for this. I learnt a lot by actually looking at this code and modifying it to extract other items in the original cell. Do you know how to add a function and argument descriptions within the function itself? I know there is way to do it if I create a separate Sub file but I prefer to have it in the function itself.

Comment: I not sure I understand what you mean by function and argument descriptions. Can you clarify.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is laid out so that the `DEL` (deliverables) are always listed before the `WKP` (Work products), there is no need for VBA.

Here is the non-vba solution:

Assuming data is column A, place this formula in B1

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(", WKP1",A1)-1)
```

And this in C1

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(", WKP1",A1)-1)
```

Then drag down.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I'll give this a try before trying VBA. And yes, the DELs are always listed before WKP. What does the "-1" mean in both functions?

Comment: One more question, what if a cell in Col A does not have WKPs but only DELs. When I tried LEFT(A1,FIND(.., I get a "#VALUE" error. Then, I tried to make an IF statement with a FIND inside it but it didn't work.

Comment: @user1738868  `-1 ->` just subtracts 1 from the place where `, WKP` starts so as to not leave any hanging `spaces` or `commas`. You could change the ", WKP1" to " WKP1" and remove the -1 I think, or something to that effect. `Re: Errors->` If you are on XL2007 or above, you can wrap your formula in a `IFERROR` statement. If on 2003 you can write `=IF(ISERROR(formula,"",formula)`